# How can I get Jenkins pipeline to run a specific cypress test folder to run using a single command when pushing changes to my web app

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I have the following directory structure for working with Cypress:

```
cypress-automation
    cypress
        fixtures
        integration
           apps
              one-spec.js
           pulse
              sample-spec.js
              another-spec.js
        examples
        plugins
        screenshots
        support
        videos
    node_modules
    cypress.env.json
    cypress.json 
    package-lock.json
    package.json
```

I want to be able to have a command to be able to target the pulse folder test when a specific push has been made. Has anyone made an attempt or has this working that can help me out ?

Edit: Lets say i have a few specs in the app folder. now if i wanted a way to run those specs instead with a specific command when pushing new code changes, is that possible. I want to be able to run specific folders with different scenarios so I am not always running everything everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the command like this:

```js
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/pulse/*-spec.js"
```

You can also pre-define commands with specific folders in your `package.json` like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test:pulse": "cypress run --spec \"cypress/integration/pulse/*-spec.js\""
  "test:app": "cypress run --spec \"cypress/integration/app/*-spec.js\""
}
```

Now when you want to run pulse tests you can just run `npm run test:pulse` or for app you can run `npm run test:app`

Comment: I do have that for now, but let say i have a few specs in the app folder. now if i wanted a way to run those specs instead with a specific command when pushing new code changes, is that possible. I want to be able to run specific folders with different scenarios so I am not always running everything everytime.